# Jenkins Docker container not copying pre-installed plugins to JENKINS_HOME on start

Tags: jenkins, docker

I cannot seem to get Jenkins to copy pre-installed plugins to the expected `/var/jenkins_home/plugins` directory on startup as documented [here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker#preinstalling-plugins).

I'm using a very basic Dockerfile:

```
FROM jenkins:alpine
USER root
RUN /usr/local/bin/install-plugins.sh ssh-agent
USER jenkins
```

When I build the container, it says the plugins installed successfully and after I run the container:

- the plugins do not appear in the web console and restarting does not
  fix the issue.
- `/var/jenkins_home/plugins` inside the container is empty
- `/usr/share/jenkins/ref/plugins` does not exist inside the container

---

**However** I do see the expected plugins inside of 
`/var/jenkins_home/war/WEB-INF/detached-plugins`

I attempted to copy them by adding:

```
RUN cp -R /var/jenkins_home/war/WEB-INF/detached-plugins/* /var/jenkins_home/plugins/`
```

but then I get the following error during build:

```
cp: cannot stat '/var/jenkins_home/war/WEB-INF/detached-plugins/*': No such file or directory`
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was building and running my container like so:

```
docker build .
docker run -d -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 jenkins
```

So of course the container I was running didn't have the plugins, it wasn't based on the image which I had just built!

I should have been doing something like this in order to run my own image:

```
docker build --tag custom_jenkins .
docker run -d -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 custom_jenkins
```

Docker 101 :-/

Answer (score 4):

According the documentation on [docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/jenkins/).

Create your dockerfile

```
FROM jenkins:alpine
COPY plugins.txt /usr/share/jenkins/plugins.txt
RUN /usr/local/bin/plugins.sh /usr/share/jenkins/plugins.txt
```

Plugins.txt is in the same folder als your dockerfile. Example content:

```
git:3.0.0
greenballs:1.15
```

Build the new image:

```
$ docker build -t my-jenkins:2.0 .
```

You'll already see this:

```
Step 3 : RUN /usr/local/bin/plugins.sh /usr/share/jenkins/plugins.txt
 ---> Running in 5df5d14d8571
Analyzing war: /usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war
Downloading git:3.0.0
Downloading greenballs:1.15
---------------------------------------------------
INFO: Successfully installed 2 plugins.
---------------------------------------------------
```

Start the container to verify:

```
$ docker run -d -p 8080:8080 my-jenkins:2.0  

$ docker exec -it e1f8ca9302d8 bash
bash-4.3$ ls -l /var/jenkins_home/plugins/
total 2232
drwxr-xr-x 5 jenkins jenkins    4096 Dec 23 10:29 git
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins jenkins 2152524 Dec 23 10:29 git.jpi
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins jenkins       0 Dec 23 10:29 git.jpi.pinned
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins jenkins       6 Dec 23 10:29 git.jpi.version_from_image
drwxr-xr-x 9 jenkins jenkins    4096 Dec 23 10:29 greenballs
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins jenkins  111507 Dec 23 10:29 greenballs.jpi
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins jenkins       0 Dec 23 10:29 greenballs.jpi.pinned
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins jenkins       5 Dec 23 10:29 greenballs.jpi.version_from_image
```

Or check in the webconsole. The greenballs plugin is easy to verify. After a succesful build you'll get a green ball instead of a blue.

Comment: Thanks for the response, this is a perfectly valid alternative to my method. BOTH methods should work, however it turns out I was doing something very silly :-/ See my answer.